# Troubleshooting op-amp circuit and compactor for buzzer

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

I tried building a radiation detector (cheap photodiode Geiger counter) on perfboard:
http://opengeiger.de/StuttgarterGeigerleThruHole_en.pdf

More details [here](http://opengeiger.de/StuttgarterGeigerleV1_en.pdf). With the circuit was turned on, without any photodiode excitation, in green are voltage readings:
[image]

The designer assumes a 1nA peak of the detector current impulse.

I connected the output of the second TL072 op-amp to a signal generator, then input 1 V peak. Nothing happened. I just want the speaker to work ([datasheet](http://www.puiaudio.com/pdf/AST-03208MR-R.pdf)). Any recommendations or things that stick out to you before I calculate, maybe simulate, if those are the correct values?

Comment: Are you sure the speaker is completely silent?  An LM358 does not make much output current, not nearly enough to drive a speaker to "normal" volume.  AND, there is a 1K resistor in series with the speaker; if the speaker is 8 ohm, that is a 99% amplitude reduction.

Comment: Took out the series 1k resistor and swapped out a [buzzer](http://www.puiaudio.com/pdf/AI-1223-TWT-3V-2-R.pdf) for the speaker, and still couldn't hear anything.

Comment: Had the trimmer cap in wrong. Now it makes a soft speaker noise with no excitation, and when covered, goes silent.